TensorFlow EMNIST predictions
I am new to tensorflow and I have currently made a model of the eMNIST letters dataset that I would like to use to predict handwriting. Currently, I am giving the model the lowercase version of the letter 'a'. When I execute the lines of code I have provided, I receive multiple output arrays that do not make much sense. The arrays all have 27 indexes while the emnist letters should only contain 26, correct?
Here are the images:
Code I used to test the given image (a jpg file)
Output prediction arrays
I am guessing that these indexes are corresponding with the given letters, however the letter 'a' that I have given the model should be in one of the first index.
Not sure where to go from here. I am curious on what these indexes mean.
Thank you for any help in advance.
